# A recommender system using Facebook Profile Data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm creating a recommender system that issues recommendations based on Facebook profile data. So I've set up a basic framework for a user to login through Facebook connect, authorize permissions to the application, and land on the redirect page which displays the users profile data in JSON as a series of arrays (which I've pasted below). So now I need to create a setup that issues recommendations based on specific pieces of data. For example: if the user went to this school, or is majoring in this, or lives here, or is this old, recommend this. I'm used to doing this with variables in PHP, usually through manually submitted forms. So how do I take this data output, which I obviously don't want displayed on the browser in the final product, turn it into variables on the server side so I can create if else statements to issue recommendations. I would use Facebook object ID numbers instead of text, i.e. I would identify a school or major by it's Facebook ID rather than it's actual name like UCF or Finance.

So there are essentially two things I'm trying to accomplish. 1. Take the data off the browser and analyze it on the server side in PHP. 2. Turn the data into some form that I can call in if_else statements individually (and collectively) to issue if else statement expressions (preferably in PHP). Right now the data below is being called collectively via $userInfo so there's no way to call any of it individually.

I am calling quite a bit of data from the user profile so it's a difficult task I know and I'm relatively new to programming (about 9 months). I just seem to be completely lost. Any guidance would be tremendously appreciated.

How the data is currently being called via Graph API:

```
if ($user){
        //get user basic description
        $userInfo           = $facebook->api("/$user");
```

How data is being displayed on client side:

```
 <td>
                <!-- Data retrived from user profile are shown here -->
                <div class="box">
                    <b>User Information using Graph API</b>
                    <?php d($userInfo); ?>
                </div>
            </td>
```

And the output below:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 619011251
    [name] => Matt McClintock
    [first_name] => Matt
    [last_name] => McClintock
    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/MattMcClint
    [username] => MattMcClint
    [birthday] => 08/15/1988
    [hometown] => Array
    (
        [id] => 102184499823699
        [name] => Montreal, Quebec
    )

[location] => Array
    (
        [id] => 108288992526695
        [name] => Orlando, Florida
    )

[education] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [school] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 111894272160018
                        [name] => Spanish River Community High School
                    )

                [year] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 137616982934053
                        [name] => 2006
                    )

                [type] => High School
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [school] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 35078114590
                        [name] => University of Central Florida
                    )

                [year] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 118118634930920
                        [name] => 2012
                    )

                [concentration] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 104076956295773
                                [name] => Computer Science
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 107870585903083
                                [name] => Finance
                            )

                    )

                [type] => College
            )

    )

[gender] => male
[email] => matt@smartkrawl.com
[timezone] => -4
[locale] => en_US
[verified] => 1
[updated_time] => 2011-10-16T17:45:56+0000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting I found a simple yet difficult to implement solution. First you need to initialize the SDK right off the bat like this:

```
<?php
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

$config = array(
'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

Then we make sure a user is currently logged in and prompt them to log in if they're not:

```
<?
if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');


  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}

?>
```

Now you can call any of the data in the Facebook user's profile, like so:

```
<?php
if ($user_profile['education'][0]['school']['id']=='111894272160018') {
    echo "Finally. It worked";
}
```